# Spring Batch 2.2.3 exception - Shouldn't be illegal to access field 'serialVersionUID'

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, serialversionuid

I have a Spring Batch job that started throwing this odd exception.

I wish I had more information than this stack trace, and I might, but I just don't know what to provide.

Searching around I've only found one other person with this particular error, but no replies as of August 2013. [spring.io forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/130487-illegalaccessexception-can-not-set-static-final-long-field-when-launching-batch-job)

Would anyone have any suggestions? Thanks /w

```
10:44:15,096 ERROR AbstractJob,pool-15-thread-1:326 - Encountered fatal error executing job
org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Flow execution ended unexpectedly
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:141)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:301)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:127)
        at com.example.batch.RunScheduler.run(RunScheduler.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor139.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:64)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowExecutionException: Ended flow=sourceJob at state=sourceJob.sourceStep1 with exception
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:161)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:131)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shouldn't be illegal to access field 'serialVersionUID': java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Can not set static final long field org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution.serialVersionUID to java.lang.Long
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:573)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:547)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapStepExecutionDao.copy(MapStepExecutionDao.java:59)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapStepExecutionDao.updateStepExecution(MapStepExecutionDao.java:109)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update(SimpleJobRepository.java:189)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor144.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.update(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:183)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:137)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:152)
        ... 20 more
```

Comment: If you can open a Jira issue with this and a test case, it would be helpful to address.

Comment: @MichaelMinella, I'll see if I can devise a test case. It's somewhat difficult because not all of our devs are seeing the issue - same for test machines. Additionally I've never seen it in a unit/it test. Would a Jira issue sans a test be okay until I can devise one?

Comment: The Jira issue would be a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Spring 3.2.0, and possibly other versions.  See the [source code to org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(Class,FieldCallback,FieldFilter) at line 565](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-core/3.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.java#ReflectionUtils.doWithFields%28java.lang.Class,org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.FieldCallback,org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.FieldFilter%29).  The comment on this line suggests that the code should skip static and/or final fields, but there is no code to actually implement this test.  Certainly, the exception being thrown is an expected result of attempting to modify a static final field (non-static final fields can be modified via reflection, but static final is treated as a compile-time constant so modification is disallowed).

Comment: The problem affects only in-memory `StepExecutionDao` impl (`MapStepExecutionDao`) and not the jdbc counterpart; the problem is the missing use of `FieldFilter`; you can workaround create a custom `MapStepExecutionDao` and use `ReflectionUtils.shallowCopyFieldState` as `private static void MapStepExecutionDao.copy(StepExecution sourceExecution, StepExecution targetExecution)` implementation

Comment: Looking `StepExecution` I didn't see any `serialVersionUID` field; is a synthetic one? but synthetics should not be returned by `Class.getDeclaredFields()`; or I am missing something?

Comment: I believe it's because `StepExecution` implements `Serializable` and one is auto-generated if not defined @bellabax.

Comment: Yep. but does `Class.getDeclaredFields()` method return syntethic fields?

Comment: @bellabax, I switched from `org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean` to `JobRepositoryFactoryBean` and configured the job repository bean as such and so far so good. `<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
<property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="ISOLATION_DEFAULT"/>
</bean>`

Comment: Here is the Jira issue [#BATCH-2157](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2157). According to a comment on [16 Jan 2015](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2157?focusedCommentId=111664&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-111664) it was fixed in spring batch version 3.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

The issue referred to by Jules was fixed. Just upgrade to spring batch version 3.0.2.RELEASE or later.

Answer (score 0):

If upgrade to Spring Batch Core 3.0.2 is hard (for any reason) and if you are using jacoco integration through Maven, a solution could be exclude Spring classes in jacoco integration :

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Avoid BATCH-2157 until Spring Batch Core 3.0.2 -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>...</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/springframework/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        [...]
    </plugins>
    [...]
</pluginManagement>
```

The Maven tests are passing with that ; but the impact on code coverage is not qualified (it would be minimal).